# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[13], "@react-navigation/elements").SafeAreaProviderCompat')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I upgraded to react native 0.70.5 and also upgraded react-navigation/native to version 6.0.13 and react-navigation/native-stack to version 6.9.1, after successfully running the project on ios I get the following exceptions:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[13], "@react-navigation/elements").SafeAreaProviderCompat')
Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run yarn or npm install.
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/src/index.tsx", which threw an exception: Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run yarn or npm install.
```

I cleaned the project and re install everything but the issue persisted.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPJ9O.png)

I cleaned everything (node_modules) Pods builds... But the error persist, I tried to re install react-native-screens@3.18.2 and react-native-safe-area-context@4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because of some missing dependencies for react-navigation.

Try

```html
npm i @react-native-masked-view/masked-view @react-navigation/elements
```

Run **pod install**.
Then clean the build folder and rebuild the project.

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution above does not work. 
Could there be an explanation on why we are adding these libraries and how they solve the problem?